# Solving cubic equation with general expression $ax^3+bx^2+(c-j)x+(d-m)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, cubics

I am trying to solve the equation $ax^3+bx^2+(c-j)x+(d-m)=0$ to find an expression for all three roots. I found this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5ZtW.png) but whenever I try and solve it by substituting values in I always get imaginary numbers as answers for example the equation $x^3-2x+0.25$ I get imaginary numbers as the answers for x even when there are 3 clear real roots. I was wondering if somebody could run through a step by step solution to $x^3-2x+0.25$ or suggest another method for solving $ax^3+bx^2+(c-j)x+(d-m)=0$ ?
Thanks

Comment: Here is a step-by-step solution in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1670993/4781).

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the cubic formula? Here's a link: http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/

Alternatively, in high school, for such polynomial equations, we tried substituting possible factors into the equation (e.g. for this case 1, 1/4, 1/2), then doing synthetic division on that.

Here's a more detailed note on factoring: http://www.wtamu.edu/academic/anns/mps/math/mathlab/col_algebra/col_alg_tut7_factor.htm

Comment: Please do not have most of your answer rely on links, as linnks may be broken later. Instead, put what you want to say into your answer instead of linking.

Comment: I tried with the cubic formula, however each time I did that I seemed to be getting a negative inside the square root and therefore an imaginary number even though it was clear there were real roots. And the substitution method doesn't work as I am trying to find a general formula